# How to associate a URL to an application using Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, url, protocols

From the command prompt it's possible to run for example "open http://www.example.com" and have that homepage displayed in the default browser.

Similarly you can run "open callto:xyz123" to open up a skype-call to user xyz123.

I'd like to do the same with a customized web browser without replacing the default web browser. My idea is to register a new protocol (mb) so that when I run "open mb://www.example.com" that web page will open up in this new custom browser.

How can an application register itself to handle URL's with a certain protocol?

Comment: Found it, it's in the Info.plist file using the key CFBundleURLTypes

Comment: Put this in an actual answer and mark it answered for good housekeeping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it, it's in the Info.plist file using the key CFBundleURLTypes